# Extract specific rows using R

Tags: r, genetics

I have a vector of ID's which describe membership to a group. Each ID appears only once in the list.

Example:

```
GO:0006169
GO:0032238
GO:0046086
GO:0006154
GO:0046085
GO:0004001
```

I also have a table (3 columns,  74985 rows, no headers) containing individual ID's in V1 (recorded as a number), group ID's in V2. And a short description of the group in V3.

Example:

```
1 GO:0003674                                           molecular_function
1 GO:0005576                                         extracellular region
1 GO:0008150                                           biological_process
2 GO:0001869 negative regulation of complement activation, lectin pathway
2 GO:0004867                 serine-type endopeptidase inhibitor activity
2 GO:0005515                                              protein binding
```

Each individual can belong to more than one group and each group can have more than one individual in it. In the example individual 1 is in group  `GO:0003674, GO:0005576 and GO:0008150`.

I would like to extract and retain from the table every row (that is to say every group) where the group ID matches the vector of group ID's. Some of the ID's in the first vector have no match in the table. I've tried using the merge function but without success it seems to include the same individual multiple times in a group.

Answer (score 3):

I guess with table you mean data frame - if not, just convert and maybe adjust column names using `names()` or work with indexes instead.

Lookup indexes in df with `which()`, then use those for extracting appropriate rows:

```
> df <- data.frame(g=1:10,v=1:10)
> v <- c(3,4,7,33)
> df[df$g %in% v,]
  g v
3 3 3
4 4 4
7 7 7
```

Another option would be using `sqldf` and then handle the data frames like tables with SQL.

Comment: The `which()` is unnecessary - `%in%` returns a logical vector, `df[df$g %in% v,]` will do it

Comment: It was a dataframe yes. It's giving me something but I seem to have fewer individuals in each group in results than in the initial dataframe. New_data=old_data[old_data$V2 %in% Vector_of_ID,]

Answer (score 2):

Using `merge`:

```
#dummy - GO dataframe
df1 <- read.table(text="GO:0006169
GO:0032238
GO:0046086
GO:0006154
GO:0046085
GO:0004001",col.names=c("GO_ID"))

#dummy - sample
df2 <- read.table(text="
1 GO:0003674 molecular_function
1 GO:0046086 extracellular_region
1 GO:0008150 biological_process
1 GO:0046085 xxx
2 GO:0046085 negative_xx_lectinpathway
2 GO:0004867 serine-type_endopeptidase_inhibitor
2 GO:0005515 protein_binding",col.names=c("Sample_ID","GO_ID","Description"))

#output
merge(df1,df2)
#GO_ID Sample_ID               Description
#1 GO:0046085         1                       xxx
#2 GO:0046085         2 negative_xx_lectinpathway
#3 GO:0046086         1      extracellular_region
```

Comment: +1 but this would not cover for more than one ID, or it would return a Sample_ID and Sample_ID_2 and then crash, if I remember well.

Comment: If there is Sample_ID 1 that have GO:0046085 and Sample_ID that have the same what will happen? In that case I think it would acts like I said in the previous comment